# Adding user to mongodb admin DB makes it impossible for me to use HTTP admin interface

Tags: mongodb

I added one user to the admin database of a fresh MongoDB install (v2.2) and now the monitoring user interface normally found at http://mysite.com:28017 requires authentication; yet when I authenticate using the credentials of that user I just added I'm still denied.  Is it not enough to add a user to admin?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any firewall settings or the port is available to the world (if it's an actual domain).

How did you ran the mongodb?

```
db.serverCmdLineOpts()
```

Maybe a screenshot (imgur.com) might help, to see the error.

Comment: The port is definitely available to "the world"; it's only when I add a single user to the admin DB that this happens.   If I remove the user from the admin DB, then I can see the HTTP interface again.  So not a port problem.  I suspect that I'm not properly adding users.  Checking on config.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by going back and more carefully reviewing [the security and authentication documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication).  Specifically, I stopped all servers in the replica set, turned off security, removed all users from the admin database (it's a new install), and started the replica set.  Then I added the user, restarted the replica set with security enabled (--keyfile), hit the admin interface at :28017, and when prompted for auth, used that newly-created admin credential successfully. Just needed to be careful.